# Logout on each time cleared the cache in Neos

Tags: neoscms

I am using Neos 1.1.0 beta1

I am using below command to clear the cache.

```
FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:flush --force
```

Each time when i clear the cache it will logout from backend.
It is very difficult if multiple users working on Backend.

I have also tried to use below command to clear the cache but it has no effect in Frontend

```
./flow flow:cache:flush --force
```

Could you please suggest me ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on changes to the code of your website you should do that in development context to avoid the need to flush the cache all the time. In Production you will need to clear caches for every change of your code. Currently there is no way to avoid loosing the sessions. We are working to change this.

From version 1.2 on you have an additional command to clear one specific cache:

```
./flow flow:cache:flushone TYPO3_TypoScript_Content
```

will for example flush only the content caches of Neos. This will leave your session intact.

Additionally from Neos 2.0 on you can define persistent caches that are not cleared by the `cache:flush`command but need to be flushed specifically. So sessions would be a good candidate for that.